# Why isn't data being inserted into MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm brand new to PHP/MYSql and I'm trying to build a form that submits to MYSql.  Here's the form code:

```
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last"><br>
    Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br>

    <input type="Submit">
    </form>
```

Here's the insert.php:

```
<?php 
include "db-connect.php";

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$first', '$last', '$phone')";
$result= mysql_query($query);

if($result) {
    echo "Data entered Successfully";
} else {
    echo "You suck at coding";
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

Again I'm really new, so if you could explain it to me like I'm 5 that'd be great.

EDIT: I built the table with the myphpadmin gui.

The fields are:

id: INT, Primary, auto-increment
first: varchar (50)
last: varchar (50)
phone: varchar (25)

**EDIT2: Following Esailija's advice I added the mysql_error() function.  Here's the response: "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1"**

Comment: can you show the structure of your table?

Comment: If you're brand new to PHP/MySQL, forget about the `mysql_*` functions and stick with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Replace `echo "You suck at coding";` with `echo mysql_error();`, it will be vastly more useful

Comment: @hope - yeah man a guy with 33k rep doesn't know this? And a guy just starting probably doesn't have a site where it matters

Comment: can you do tell us what is in db-connect.php and do var_dump($_POST)..

Comment: Seconded. Unless you can show why it's failing, it's hard to respond (despite your impressive age of 5)

Comment: You probably need to list the columns you are inserting into (but not the id column) after the table name and then not supply the '' for the id column. `insert into users (first, last, phone) values ('$first', '$last', '$phone')`.  However this is subject to SQL injection attacks, I'd definitely go the PDO route.

Comment: You should minimally escape special characters before inserting. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @Esailija Thanks for that.  None of the tutorials I've been working on have mentioned that error function yet.

Comment: @NewToCode - Since you are new to PHP/MySQL do not waste time learning deprecated function mysql_query. Use mysqli or PDO for database functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (first, last, phone) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$phone')";
```

...where first, last, and phone are the actual names of the fields in your table.

And +1 for replacing echo "You suck at coding" with echo mysql_error(). :)

Comment: And along with what @Kai Qing mentioned before, comment out the mysql_error() when you go live. You will also want to escape the variables before inserting them into your database to prevent injection attacks: `$first = mysql_real_escape_string($first);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure since you are not providing your mysql table schema.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (first, last, phone)
          VALUES ('" . $first . "', '" . $last . "', '" . $phone . "')
```

If your `id` column is set to INTEGER and not `AUTO_INCREMENT`, make sure to insert the proper integer to the query, ie:

```
$id = 72;
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('" . $id . "', '" . $first . "', '" . $last . "', '" . $phone . "')
```

But if it's `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then the first code should be fine.

Comment: In the first one you're not providing the ID. How does MySQL know what columns the other values refer to?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first`, `last`, `phone`) VALUES (NULL, '$first', '$last', '$phone')";
```

This is a more complete version of the query that includes the names of the columns to be inserted.  Also ensure that you do not have any quotes in the fields being added to the query($first, $last, $phone).

Comment: you dont even need to include id in this case

Answer (score 0):

When you do `INSERT` without specifying the fields, MySQL assumes you're inserting all the fields in the order in which they were declared. Since `id` is a number, it can't be set to a string. It's best practice to specify field names. If the table gets more fields, for example, it won't break your existing code.

What nobody has said yet (by the time I started writing this) is that you have a terrible SQL injection hole with your code. Sticking with the legacy `mysql` interface in PHP (not upgrading to `mysqli` or `PDO`), here's how you would do it without having to worry about [little Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/):

```
<?php 
include "db-connect.php";

$query = sprintf(
  "INSERT INTO users (first, last, phone) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first']),
  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last']),
  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone'])
);
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    echo 'Data entered "Successfully".';
} else {
    echo 'You suck at coding because: ', mysql_error();
}

?>
```

P.S. May I also suggest the use of `register_shutdown_function` within "db-connect.php" to close the database connection? I would also suggest keeping track of the `$cid` which is returned from `mysql_connect(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You do the following:

1) Forget about `mysql_*` functions and code your project the right way from the beginning. Any tutorials or whatever you're looking through that try to teach you how to do PHP+MySQL that use any functions at all that start with `mysql_` push the back button on your browser. Any new projects should use either PDO or mysqli. Right from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/mysql_query) is a big red warning discouraging you from using these functions. They will be removed in future versions of PHP and for good reasons. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).

2) Any variables coming from the user should be considered tainted. This includes `$_POST` variables. The best way to deal with this is prepared statements, which is their primary purpose (and they're also faster for multiple queries).

```
// Connect to the DB substituting the values for your values:
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_database', $db_user, $db_password);

// Get PDO to display errors. You can comment this out for the live script
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO_ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Prepare the statement to be used during your query
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first, last, phone) VALUES ( :first , :last , :phone )");

// Bind the values to the prepared statement
$stmt->bindValue( ':first' , $first );
$stmt->bindValue( ':last' , $last );
$stmt->bindValue( ':phone' , $phone );

// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();
```

Anything here can also be wrapped around a try-catch block if you wish to gracefully handle the errors produced.

Comment: I'll definitely look into PDO tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: It may seem more complicated at first, but it will save you a lot of headaches down the road. Trust me. If you prefer procedural programming, you might want to look into mysqli instead of PDO. PDO is my personal preference though.

Comment: I have no preferences yet because PHP is my first venture into programming outside of html & css.